# ClosedXml : Set column's name in a table with spaces

Tags: c#, .net, excel, closedxml

I'm trying to create a table in excel with closedxml and i want it to be having names it's columns with spaces as in thhis picture [Table with spaces in its column's names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Buaf.png). in the default case the names should not have spaces, i tried rewrite these names after creating the table but the names become transparent even if i mmake sure that the core is black.

the script of creating the table is :

```
public static void CreateTable(IXLWorksheet ws, int beginRow, int beginColumn, List<SitesTableModel> list)
{ 
    ws.Cell(beginRow, beginColumn).InsertTable(list.AsEnumerable());
    var range5 = ws.Range(beginRow, beginColumn, beginRow+list.Count, beginColumn+5);

    range5.Style.Alignment.Vertical = XLAlignmentVerticalValues.Top;
    range5.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.TealBlue;
    range5.Style.Font.FontName = "Arial";
    range5.Style.Font.FontSize = 10;
    range5.Style.Alignment.WrapText = true;

    Cell cell = new Cell
    {    
        fontColor = XLColor.Black,
        textValue = "Nom du site",
        fontName = "Arial",
        bold = false,
        fontSize = 10,
        alignment = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Left,    
    };

    SetCellValue(ws, beginRow, beginColumn, cell);
    cell.textValue = "Adresse d'audit";
    SetCellValue(ws, beginRow, beginColumn+1, cell);
    cell.textValue = "Certifications demandées";
    SetCellValue(ws, beginRow, beginColumn+2, cell);
    cell.textValue = "Activités du site";
    SetCellValue(ws, beginRow, beginColumn+3, cell);
    cell.textValue = "Produits du site";
    SetCellValue(ws, beginRow, beginColumn+4, cell);
}
```

Comment: There was a recent change that might fix this issue. Please try v0.93.0-beta1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no expert in ClosedXML, but it looks like you are creating one cell and using it over and over. I should think that something like this would work:

```
public static void CreateTable(IXLWorksheet ws, int beginRow, int beginColumn, List<SitesTableModel> list)
{ 
    var wsTable = ws.Cell(beginRow, beginColumn).InsertTable(list.AsEnumerable());

    // Removed range stuff I don't understand

    wsTable.Cell(beginRow, beginColumn).SetValue("Nom du site");
    wsTable.Cell(beginRow, beginColumn+1).SetValue("Adresse d'audit");
    wsTable.Cell(beginRow, beginColumn+2).SetValue("Certifications demandées");
    wsTable.Cell(beginRow, beginColumn+3).SetValue("Activités du site");
    wsTable.Cell(beginRow, beginColumn+4).SetValue("Produits du site");
}
```

Edit: There seems to be a good table intro here: https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML-wiki/blob/master/Inserting-Tables.md

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem.

PS : there was a little mistake, it should be like this :
            wsTable.Cell(1, 1).SetValue("Nom du site");
            wsTable.Cell(1, 2).SetValue("Adresse d'audit");
            wsTable.Cell(1, 3).SetValue("Certifications demandées");
            wsTable.Cell(1, 4).SetValue("Activités du site");
            wsTable.Cell(1, 5).SetValue("Produits du site");